# Type Error after providing image after reading it from OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, yolo

I am trying to use YOLO Object detection first time and during this I am getting Type Error after proving image to program. I am reading image  from opencv by using cv2.imread() function and providing it to yolo after some image processing but I am getting "Type Error".

I am providing images of code where I am getting error:

```
  def ocr_function(image): 
    start = time()
    try:
        ocr_threshold = 0.4

        ocr_weights = b'data/ocr/ocr-net.weights'
        ocr_netcfg  = b'data/ocr/ocr-net.cfg'
        ocr_dataset = b'data/ocr/ocr-net.data'

        ocr_net  = dn.load_net(ocr_netcfg, ocr_weights, 0)
        ocr_meta = dn.load_meta(ocr_dataset)

        print("performing OCR at: ", os.getcwd())

        print("\tScanning %s" %image)

        image = cv2.imread(image_path)
        image = preprocess(image)
        show(image, "provided image")        

        R,(width,height) = detect(ocr_net, ocr_meta, image, thresh=ocr_threshold, nms=None)

        if len(R):
            L = dknet_label_conversion(R,width,height)
            L = nms(L,.45)

            L.sort(key=lambda x: x.tl()[0])
            lp_str = ''.join([chr(l.cl()) for l in L])

            print ('\t\tLP: %s' % lp_str)
```

And I am getting this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-1-c25d751af85c>", line 86, in ocr_function
    R,(width,height) = detect(ocr_net, ocr_meta, imageROT, thresh=ocr_threshold, nms=None)
  File "/home/infinity/Desktop/NEW ALPR/LPD/darknet/python/darknet.py", line 126, in detect
    im = load_image(image, 0, 0)
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

Comment: post the code instead of screenshot

Comment: I edited the question and republished it after giving a code.

Comment: what is the type of image when you pass it as argument for `detect`. I mean what is the output of `print(type(image))`

Comment: After reading image with cv2 the type is ndarray that is  **<class 'numpy.ndarray'>**.

Comment: After the preprocess step too?

Comment: yes, after reading image from opencv I got the image type as ** <class 'numpy.ndarray'>** and I also checked the its type after prepeocess again I got ** <class 'numpy.ndarray'>**. But after passing that to yolo detect function it is giving error

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `load_image` function expects a `pointer to data array`.

Code from `darknet` library's `detect` function:

```py
load_image = lib.load_image_color
load_image.argtypes = [c_char_p, c_int, c_int]
load_image.restype = IMAGE
```

So I would suggest you to use the `__arrayinterface__` to pass the data array.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.interface.html

```
image_data = image.__array_interface__['data'][0]
R,(width,height) = detect(ocr_net, ocr_meta, image_data, thresh=ocr_threshold, nms=None)
```